# I get segmentation fault when trying to run this recursive code in Assembly

Tags: assembly, recursion, x86-64

I recently started learning Assembly x86-64 and wrote a program to calculate the factorial of a number entered by the user. It should do it using a recursive subroutine however when I run the code I come across "Segmentation Fault" after the user enters a value.

Is there any way to solve it and what do I need to change? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
mystring: .asciz "Assignment 4: factorial\nEnter a value\n"
string: .asciz "The result is: %d\n"
nrstring: .asciz "%d"

.global main

main:
pushq %rbp                   # put rbp on stack 
movq %rsp, %rbp              # set base pointer on stack pointer

movq $0, %rax                # set rdi to 0
movq $mystring, %rdi         # set variable mystring in rdi
call printf                  # call printf routine

subq $8, %rsp                # place stack for variable
leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi          # stack addressen in rsi   
movq $nrstring, %rdi         # set scanf in rdi
movq $0, %rax                # no vector for scanf
call scanf                   # call scanf

movq -8(%rbp), %rsi          # set input in rsi 
call factorial               # call factorial

movq %rax, %rsi              # total value from rax to rsi
movq $0, %rax                # empty rax
movq $string, %rdi           # place text in rdi 
call printf                  # print text


movq $0, %rdi                # set rdi to 0 for next time
call exit                    # call exit

factorial:
    cmp %rsi, 1
    jne  fact_1
    mov %rsp,%rsi
    ret 

fact_1:
   push %rsi
   dec %rsi
   call factorial
   pop %rsi
   imul %rax,%rsi
   ret


end:
popq %rax                   # total in rax
movq %rbp, %rsp             # set stack pointer to old value
popq %rbp                   # set base pointer to old value
ret                         # return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn to use a debugger so you can fix your own errors.
A debugger would have told you the fault is on the line `cmp %rsi, 1`. While that looks all right, the cpu still doesn't like it. If you examine it more closely, you might notice that `1` is not an immediate, but an address, due to the missing `$` sign. That is what's causing the fault. The solution is simple, use `cmp $1, %rsi` (note you need to swap the operands because you can only use an immediate as first operand).

This will take care of the fault, but won't make your code work. Think about what should happen if `rsi` is equal to `1`? You should return a result of `1`, either explicitly, or by returning `rsi`. The return value belongs in `rax`, as you know. I don't understand what you tried to do with `mov %rsp,%rsi` there. The correct instruction is of course `mov %rsi, %rax`.

Furthermore, you got the operands reversed for the `imul %rax,%rsi`. That will place the result into `%rsi` but you need it in `%rax`.

Fixing these problems makes your code work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've done what you suggested and it works now. I will look into using a debugger, the reason I wasnt using it now was because im new to the course at my university and this is the first time using assembly. And so far im only using Gedit and Terminal to work with assembly. 

Do you have any programs to suggest that I should install to make assembly easier to use